# Unable to find intersection of two array

Tags: c#

I have one array `int[] com` which contains two values 0 and 1 (at initial stage).

I define one more array as `String[] arr = new String[100];`

`arr` contains 6 elements which are:

```
arr[0]={4,8,10,11,12,14}
arr[1]={1,2,3,4,8,12,14}
.. arr[6]=something
```

I want to find intersection of arr[0] and arr[1], so I wrote the code as:

```
foreach (int value1 in intersect) 
{
     //perform logic
}
```

Here I should get value1 as 4,8 but i am getting value1 as 52,44.

What is wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: How about posting a compilable code showing what is not working?

Comment: Provide a minimal running test-case (preferably one that can be run in LINQPad). The `zero` and `ones` could be lies - and *something* is lying (perhaps by omission), because there are no `44` or `52` in the shown input.

Comment: @pst the test case is: 
arr[0]={4,8,10,11,12,14}
arr[1]={1,2,3,4,8,12,14}

intersection of these both gives me 1st element as 52 other as 44..i dont know how ???

Zero and one variable are proper..i debugged it and checked

Comment: I also dont know how they are coming..nothing is left..

Comment: @I4V it is working but the value of value1 i am getting is not the intersection but any random value.

Comment: I you declare the array arr like this String[] arr = new String[100]; there is no way that you can initialize array fields like this arr[0]={4,8,10,11,12,14}; arr[1]={1,2,3,4,8,12,14}; Could you post the original code?

Comment: @user2213564 I repeat my comment `How about posting a compilable code showing what is not working?` When you post a concrete code, I am sure people will answer it in seconds.

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic My program is much big,,I dont know what things should I mention here...but I declared it in String[] arr = new String[100]; way and did few operations and got the result as arr[0]={4,8,10,11,12,14}; arr[1]={1,2,3,4,8,12,14};

Comment: The arr[0] can only be one string, not an array of numbers and therefore the intersect won't work as you expect.

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic ohh is it ??
what should i do if i want to have arr[0]={4,8,10,11,12,14} then ???

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic cant i apply intersection between arr[0]={4,8,10,11,12,14}; arr[1]={1,2,3,4,8,12,14}; ????

Comment: You appear to be so busy typing that you can't pause, cut down your program to the essentials you wish to have help with (the bit which isn't working) and then post them here with a clear explanation of what you think should happen.   Please stop posting "can't I apply intersection" - we know, you said it, it just doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is what you are doing, you have string arrays not int arrays. If you do this

```
arr[0]="4,8,10,11,12,14";
arr[1]="1,2,3,4,8,12,14";
var intersection = arr[0].Intersect(arr[1]);
```

since `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are strings, you'll get as the result this list of chars `'4', ',' , '8', '1', '2'` which corresponds respectively to the integer values `52 44 56 49 50` which is exactly what you are getting.

You should declare integer matrix instead of array of strings `int [,] arr = new int[100,100];` or even better `List<List<int>>`. You can't use integers like strings, at least not in this context.

```
List<List<int>> arr = new List<List<int>>();
arr.Add(new List<int>{4,8,10,11,12,14});
arr.Add(new List<int>{1,2,3,4,8,12,14});
var intersection = arr[0].Intersect(arr[1]);
```

But if you don't believe me, and want to be sure that your previous code doesn't make sense, change the `foreach` loop and see what's happening:

```
foreach (char value1 in intersect) 
{
     //perform logic
}
```

In addition, you don't need to do this:

```
int zero= Convert.ToInt32(com[0].ToString());
int one= Convert.ToInt32(com[1].ToString());
```

You could replace it with something like:

```
int zero= com[0];
int one = com[1];
```

but nevertheless it's pointless since you can do this:

```
arr[com[0]]
arr[com[1]]
```

Comment: I cant do (arr[com[0]]).Intersect(arr[com[1]]);

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method correctly computes the intersection between arrays:

```
var a = new [] {4,8,10,11,12,14};
var b = new [] {1,2,3,4,8,12,14};
var intersection = a.Intersect(b);
// intersection:
// IEnumerable<int> { 4, 8, 12, 14 }
```

The above code - which represents a minimum *non-failing* counter example - was run in LINQPad.

Note that Intersect relies on Equals, so it's possible to "break" it:

```
var a = new object[] {4,8,10,11,12,14};
var b = new object[] {"1","2","3","4","8","12","14"};
var intersection = a.Intersect(b);
// intersection:
// IEnumerable<object> { }
```

Of course, this *doesn't* account for "random new values" - that's just a bug elsewhere.

Comment: int[] array1 = { 4, 8, 11,14 };
        int[] array2 = { 2, 3, 4,8,14,11 };

        
        var intersect = array1.Intersect(array2);

        
        foreach (int value in intersect)

        {

            

            TextBox1.Text+=value.ToString();

        }

when i run the code this way it works,,but when i do


int zero= Convert.ToInt32(com[0].ToString()); // zero gets 0, which 
is what i want

            int one= Convert.ToInt32(com[1].ToString()); //one gets 
1 which is what i want

            var intersect =  (arr[zero]).Intersect(arr[one]); 


This does not work..

Comment: cant i apply intersection between arr[0]={4,8,10,11,12,14}; arr[1]={1,2,3,4,8,12,14}; ????

Comment: Sure, you can, but either 1. **you aren't intersecting arrays of integers** or 2. **you're doing something wrong with the result**. I have provided an example showing it working. To continue having any sort of meaningful discussion, you must provide a *minimal test case of it failing*. Make sure your test-case [runs in LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) and only includes the relevant [compiling/valid] code to display the problem.